# If 75 degrees Fahrenheit is the temperature outside, and the temperature outside is rising, is 75 degrees Fahrenheit rising?

Tags: fallacies

75 degrees Fahrenheit is static. It cannot rise or fall. The statement is valid since a=b and b=c so a=c. The premises can be true.

My friend asked me this question and I believe it's an association fallacy since it can be rewritten as "if the temp is 75, and the temp is rising, then 75 is rising", giving a=b and a=c so b=c.

However, it was not phrased this way. Does this difference in phrasing make any actual difference in the logic of the statement?

Essentially, why is this statement incorrect and does this type of mistake have a name?

Comment: I would look at it this way.  When you go out into the world carrying a thermometer, then you are very likely to get what a thermometer can give you.

Comment: When you're accelerating in your car, at any given moment your speedometer tells you your instantaneous velocity. Yet your velocity is changing. "The temperature outside" is an instantaneous measurement that changes over time.

Comment: IDT numbers only refer to other numbers.

Comment: @twisteddragons This is an interesting question. We presumably all understand that the statement "*if the temp is 75, and the temp is rising, then 75 is rising*" is somehow false, and we should be able to give a convincing reason that it is.

Comment: My thermometer has a little arrow next to the temperature reading, the arrow points up, level or down. These are two different pieces of information. It could just as easily be 72 and rising, or 75 and steady. How's your bank account doing?

Comment: This could lead to some deep philosophical problem such as the category of  quantity vs quality. For your direct concern there's a subtle difference between a physical quantity such as temperature and its numerical part aka number especially according to Kantian epistemology. Thus although you've applied the important substituitability property of the equality propositional type but the actual rising component only applies to its numerical part, in summary it's our conventional conflation causes your confusion...

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest relevant discourse I could find quickly in the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/#LogiIden):

> Leibniz’s Law has itself been subject to controversy in the sense that the correct explanation of apparent counter-examples has been debated. Leibniz’s Law must be clearly distinguished from the substitutivity principle, that if “*a*” and “*b*” are codesignators (if “*a=b*” is a true sentence of English) they are everywhere substitutable *salva veritate*. This principle is trivially false. “Hesperus” contains eight letters, “Phosphorus” contains ten, but Hesperus (the Evening Star) is Phosphorus (the Morning Star). Again, despite the identity, it is informative to be told that Hesperus is Phosphorus, but not to be told that Hesperus is Hesperus (“On Sense and Reference” in Frege 1969). Giorgione was so-called because of his size, Barbarelli was not, but Giorgione was Barbarelli (Quine, “Reference and Modality”, in 1963) . It is a necessary truth that 9 is greater than 7, it is not a necessary truth that the number of planets is greater than 7, although 9 is the number of planets. The explanation of the failure of the substitutivity principle can differ from case to case. In the first example, it is plausible to say that “‘Hesperus’ contains eight letters” is not about Hesperus, but about the name, and the same is true, *mutatis mutandis*, of “‘Phosphorus’ contains ten letters”. Thus the names do not have the same referents in the identity statement and the predications. In the Giorgione/Barbarelli example this seems less plausible. Here the correct explanation is plausibly that “is so-called because of his size” expresses different properties depending on the name it is attached to, and so expresses the property of being called “Barbarelli” because of his size when attached to “Barbarelli” and being called “Giorgione” because of his size when attached to “Giorgione”. It is more controversial how to explain the Hesperus/Phosphorus and 9/the number of planets examples. Frege’s own explanation of the former was to assimilate it to the “Hesperus”/“Phosphorus” case: in “It is informative to be told that Hesperus is Phosphorus” the names do not stand for their customary referent but for their senses. A Fregean explanation of the 9/number of planets example may also be offered: “it is necessary that” creates a context in which numerical designators stand for senses rather than numbers.

Comment: I thought Hades wasn't considered a planet anymore?

Comment: @ScottRowe Pluto? I think Hesperus/Phosphorus is Venus.